# making multiple UILocalNotification

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

Im looking for making multiple UILocalNotification with different hours and dates scheduled. Im finding some answers here and i making this :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{

//1
NSCalendar *gregcalendar1 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *datecomponent1 = [gregcalendar1 components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[datecomponent1 setYear:2013];
[datecomponent1 setMonth:7];
[datecomponent1 setDay:21];
[datecomponent1 setHour:10];
[datecomponent1 setMinute:31];

UIDatePicker *dd1 = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[dd1 setDate:[gregcalendar1 dateFromComponents:datecomponent1]];


UILocalNotification *notification1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification1 setAlertBody:@"01"];
[notification1 setFireDate:dd1.date];
[notification1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];



//2
NSCalendar *gregcalendar2 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *datecomponent2 = [gregcalendar2 components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[datecomponent2 setYear:2013];
[datecomponent2 setMonth:7];
[datecomponent2 setDay:21];
[datecomponent2 setHour:10];
[datecomponent2 setMinute:32];

UIDatePicker *dd2 = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[dd2 setDate:[gregcalendar2 dateFromComponents:datecomponent2]];


UILocalNotification *notification2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification2 setAlertBody:@"02"];
[notification2 setFireDate:dd2.date];
[notification2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];



//3
NSCalendar *gregcalendar3 = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *datecomponent3 = [gregcalendar3 components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[datecomponent3 setYear:2013];
[datecomponent3 setMonth:7];
[datecomponent3 setDay:21];
[datecomponent3 setHour:10];
[datecomponent3 setMinute:33];

UIDatePicker *dd3 = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[dd3 setDate:[gregcalendar3 dateFromComponents:datecomponent3]];


UILocalNotification *notification3 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification3 setAlertBody:@"03"];
[notification3 setFireDate:dd3.date];
[notification3 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];


[application setScheduledLocalNotifications:@[notification1, notification2, notification3]];}
```

But some notification work randomly and some don't work.
how can i do, to scheduled more than one notification.

Thanks for all help...

Comment: Is the app open or closed when they don't work? And why are you using date pickers in the above code??

Comment: they don't when app is closed and open or work randomly.

Comment: and I m use date pickers to set the date component, is it the wrong way to do this ?

Comment: `[gregcalendar3 dateFromComponents:datecomponent2]` gets the date, the picker is redundant. Log the dates and all of the registered notifications. Check the time zones.

Comment: i have corrected tis one [gregcalendar3 dateFromComponents:datecomponent2] to [gregcalendar3 dateFromComponents:datecomponent3]but still work randomly

Comment: Oups it's working fine, I have just correct a synthaxe mistake...
i need stop drug... ;)
sorry and thanks.